# life cycle method for activity switch

Tags: android

I want to start an Activity (SECOND Activity) from another Activity (FIRST Activity) by calling startActivity(intent). Before I actually do it, I found people say that the lifecycle methods are called in the following order:

1. FIRST Activity onCreate
2. FIRST Activity onStart
3. FIRST Activity onResume
4. FIRST Activity onPause
5. SECOND Activity onCreate
6. SECOND Activity onStart
7. SECOND Activity onResume
8. FIRST Activity onStop

When first time i call first activity it follows

1. FIRST Activity onCreate
2. FIRST Activity onStart
3. FIRST Activity onResume

When i switches from first activity to second activity

1, First Activity onPause
2. SECOND Activity onCreate
3. SECOND Activity onStart
4. SECOND Activity onResume
5. FIRST Activity onStop

Problem is when i switches back to first activity

1. SECOND Activity onPause
2. FIRST Activity onCreate
3. FIRST Activity onStart
4. FIRST Activity onResume
5. SECOND Activity onStop

**I read activity life cycle it should call `onRestart()` when i switch from second activity to first activity if i'm not wrong.**

## Start Activity Code

```
public void goToActivity2(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

## Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: my question is when i switch from second activity to first activity why it is calling oncreate() method again of first activity.

Comment: it should call onrestart() and then onstart() and onresume() right ?

Comment: How you finishing the second one? the first will be reused only if you get it back from stack, if you startingActivity(first) you will go trough lifecycle again (theres a exception for this behaviou with some configs)

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: Here is code for passing intent to second activity   ' public void goToActivity2(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }'

Comment: Also put the code of AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I already included them in my post

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? @Roshan

Comment: No still trying to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

OnResume should be called. Don't finish first activity when you call the second one. and do what ever you want to in OnResume..
 actually you are launching the first activity again.. Instead of this use onBackPressed if you want to call onResume() of the previous activity. 
use

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

and it will do the deal for you.

Comment: can you please elaborate Don't finish first activity when you call the second one

Comment: when you pass Intent to launch second activity you 're probably using finish(); at the end of intent. don't use it

Comment: no i not using finish() i have posted my code snippet above

Comment: and how are you going from activity two to activity one..?

Comment: i m using same method as above but instead of Actvity2.class i m using Activity1.class

Comment: no.. don't use that.. actually you are launching the first activity again.. Instead of this use onBackPressed if you want to call onResume() of the previous activity.

Comment: okk so the solution is use onBackPressed to switch to first activity ?

Comment: super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Awesome Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code you must be trying to go back to Activity1 with:

Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);

If you are just using onBackPressed() there is something that is cleaning your activity from the stack and that's the reason why your activity1 is doing onCreate again, put some code of Activity2 to see what is happening.